# Hide Duplicate Entries in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, distinct

I want to make a mySQL query which selects all users' information (name, age, mobilePhone, etc.) excluding duplicates on "email" or "mobilePhone".

So, I want to avoid displaying duplicate entries for users who have registered more than once.

My query:

```
$sql = "SELECT tet.id tet_id, tet.firstName tet_fristName, tet.lastName tet_lastName,tet.image tet_image,  
                        tet.url tet_url,tet.address tet_address,tet.job tet_job,tet.age tet_age,
                        tet.mobilePhone tet_mobilePhone, tet.homePhone tet_homePhone, tet.email tet_email,
                        tet.date_of_registration tet_date_of_registration, tet.player_id tet_player_id, 
                        app.value app_value, app.date app_date
                FROM `test_players` as tet
                LEFT JOIN approved_test_players as app on app.player_id=tet.id WHERE app.value IS NULL order by tet.id desc ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: Add `SELECT DISTINCT` in the start of your query.

Comment: You need to read the SQL manual on `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`. I believe it's the latter you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT  tet.firstName as  tet_fristName, tet.lastName as  tet_lastName,tet.age as tet_age, tet.mobilePhone as tet_mobilePhone, tet.email as tet_email

 FROM `test_players` as tet 

JOIN approved_test_players as app 

ON app.player_id=tet.id 

WHERE app.value IS NULL 

order by tet.id desc
```

Try this

Answer (score -1):

```
Select id
From table group by tel
Having count(user_id)>2
```

Comment: You should add some text explaining why you think your code answers the question (incidentally, it doesn't)